# Microsoft's coding standards for ASP.NET controls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, coding-style, coding-standards

I cannot find any naming standards/conventions in MSDN for naming ASP.NET controls.

One of the following standards tends to be used by programmers:

- `lblAddress`
- `AddressLabel`
- `Address`

According to [MSDN's Name of Type Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229012%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), should we be treating ASP.NET controls as fields, hence using Pascal Case (e.g. `AddressLabel`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm for your second entry, `AddressLabel`. For a couple reasons. One, I believe that the Hungarian Notation first one is out of favor in a big way. Next, I believe that a lot of times labels precede input fields or another chunk of text, so there could be several "Address" controls and they'll need to be disambiguated in some form. Hence, `AddressLabel`.

Answer (score 6):

It's the second version, `AddressLabel`.  However,

1. If it's just a label, and you never refer to it in code, you can go with the default `label1`, `label2`, or whatever the IDE automatically assigns.
2. I prefer `uxAddressLabel` and `uxAddressTextBox`.  This causes intellisense to group all the controls together, and makes them *much* easier to refer to.  This is my only remaining use for Hungarian notation.

Comment: +1 for the ux comment idea

Answer (score 1):

Yes controls are fields of your **Page** class. You should name it with camel casing. Like **lblResult**, **grdEmployees** etc. If you do not have any good naming convention in your company then you can use Microsoft naming convention. You can read more about basic Microsoft naming convention [here](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices).

Answer (score 0):

In programming language naming convention have great benefits to reduce the effort needed to read and understand source code. It provides better understanding in case of reuse code after a long interval of time. It is an initial step for beginner to learn any programming language. It is a very important element

A good reference regarding this:http://cybarlab.blogspot.com/2013/02/standard-naming-convention-for-aspnet.html

Hope it will help you

Best regard

Comment: welcome to programmers. the question is about naming *controls*. so, your answers is not really addressing the question. the op is aware of the general benefit, otherwise he would not have asked the question in the first place ;-).